# all retrieve data from ms accesss database in php

Tags: php, odbc, ms-access-2007

Data retrieve from the ms access database 2007 in php using odbc driver. ALL data retrieve using query but its get only one record retrieve other data  is not retrieve.

below query three records but its retrieved only one data. which problem below code in php?how get all data using query from this code what's changes it?

```
 <?PHP

    include 'Connection2.php';



    $sql = "select FYearID,Description,FromDate,ToDate  from mstFinancialyear";


    $stmt = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
    //print_r($stmt);
    $rs = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT Count(*) AS counter from mstFinancialyear");

    //print_r($stmt);

    $arr = odbc_fetch_array($rs);
    $arr1 = $arr['counter'];
    $result = array(); 

    //print_r($arr);


     if (!empty($stmt)) {

            // check for empty result
            if ($arr1 > 0) {
    // print_r($stmt);

                $stmt1 = odbc_fetch_array($stmt);




               $year = array();
                $year['FYearID'] = $stmt1['FYearID'];
                $year['Description'] = $stmt1['Description'];
                $year['FromDate'] = $stmt1['FromDate'];
                $year['ToDate'] = $stmt1['ToDate'];


                // success
                $result["success"] = 1;

                // user node
                $result["year"] = array();


                array_push($result["year"], $year); 

                echo json_encode($result);

                //return true;

            } else {
                // no product found
                $result["success"] = 0;
                $result["message"] = "No product found";




                echo json_encode($result);


            }


            odbc_close($conn); //Close the connnection first
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return only a single record in the JSON data because you do not iterate through the recordset. Initially I misread that you had called `odbc_fetch_array` twice on the same recordset but upon closer inspection see that one query is imply used, as far as I can tell, to see if there are any records likely to be returned from the main query. The re-written code below has not been tested - I have no means to do so - and has a single query only but does attempt to iterate through the loop.

I included the `count` as a sub-query in the main query if for some reason the number of records was required somehow - I don't think that it is however.

```
<?php

    include 'Connection2.php';

    $result=array();

    $sql = "select 
            ( select count(*) from `mstFinancialyear` ) as `counter`,
            `FYearID`, 
            `Description`,
            `FromDate`,
            `ToDate` 
        from 
        `mstFinancialyear`";

    $stmt = odbc_exec( $conn, $sql );

    $rows = odbc_num_rows( $conn );
    /* odbc_num_rows() after a SELECT will return -1 with many drivers!! */


    /* assume success as `odbc_num_rows` cannot be relied upon */
    if( !empty( $stmt ) ) {

        $result["success"] = $rows > 0 ? 1 : 0;
        $result["year"] = array();

        /* loop through the recordset, add new record to `$result` for each row/year */
        while( $row=odbc_fetch_array( $stmt ) ){ 

            $year = array();
            $year['FYearID'] = $row['FYearID'];
            $year['Description'] = $row['Description'];
            $year['FromDate'] = $row['FromDate'];
            $year['ToDate'] = $row['ToDate'];

            $result["year"][] = $year;

        }
        odbc_close( $conn );
    }

    $json=json_encode( $result );
    echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  odbc_num_rows(): supplied resource is not a valid ODBC result resource in C:\Project\Year2.php on line 18

Comment: ah - think that should be `$rows = odbc_num_rows( $stmt );` instead